# How to checkout specific submodule branch in GitHub action?

Tags: github, github-actions, git-submodules, cicd

I have a Github workflow file with a checkout action that looks something like this:

```yaml
name: Build project

on:
  workflow_dispatch:
    # Allows for manual build trigger

jobs:
  buildForAllSupportedPlatforms:
    name: Build for ${{ matrix.targetPlatform }}
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
          submodules: true
```

This does the logical thing, it checks out the submodules with something like `submodule update --init --force`. Here's my question - **How do I make all the submodules check out on the master branch?**

Answer (score 1):

Figured out something that works - Just add another step after `uses: actions/checkout@v2`:

```yaml
      - name: Checkout master on all submodules
        run: |
          git submodule foreach git checkout master
          git submodule foreach git pull origin master
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    - name: Checkout submodule
      uses: actions/checkout@v2
      with:
        token: '${{ secrets.GITHUB_PAT }}'
        repository: myOrg/myRepo
        path: path/to/submodule
        ref: 'master'
```